# Is German "Bildung" a true etymological relative of "Bild"?

Tags: etymology

"Bild" as in "image", "picture".

"Bildung", on the other hand: "cultivation", "refinement", "education", "culture".

My dictionary excursion leads me from "Bildung" to "bilden" (definitely related, esentially the same word). According to Wiktionary, on "bilden": "from Old High German biladōn or pilidōn, **derived from the root of Bild.**"

On "Bild", on the other hand: from "Old High German bilidi, biladi, from Proto-West Germanic *biliþī."

Only the entry on "Bild" takes me all the way back to Proto-Germanic. The direct assertion "Derived from the root of Bild", in the entry on "bilden", is certainly promising as an answer, but.. Uncertainty strikes — possibly just because I don't know the first thing about Old High German. ("biladōn", "biladi", "bilidi"..)

Is it safe to assume that both "Bildung" and "Bild" in modern German stems from the Proto-Germanic word that comes up here?

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bild
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bilden
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/bili%C3%BE%C4%AB

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Bildung

Comment: Many of the German entries in Wiktionary are incomplete, so you should not rely on it as your sole source of information. DWDS usually was more complete etymologies, but they're written in a terse style with many abbreviations and acronyms, which make them difficult for learners to read. But the upshot seems to be that *bilidi* is the common OHG (=ahd) ancestor. As for the difference in meanings, chalk that up to the 1200 years that have elapsed between OHG and modern German.

Answer (score 6):

One could write a very extensive answer on that, but I will try to break it down to your particular question. Just to be sure this detail isn't missed: [*-ung*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ung#German) and [*-en*](https://homepages.uni-tuebingen.de/henrike.laehnemann/suffixe.htm#ung) are derivative suffixes, the morphological root of *Bild/bild-en/Bild-ung/ein-bild-en/…* is definitely *-bild-*.

It is safe to assume that *Bildung* (= 11th century OHG *bildunga*) was long ago derived from *bilden* (= 8th century OHG *biliden/bilidōn*) by the [still productive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ung#German) suffix [*-ung(a)*](https://homepages.uni-tuebingen.de/henrike.laehnemann/suffixe.htm#ung) (see also [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-unga#Suffix_2)). At that time, however, *bilden* chiefly meant *to form* and did not at all mean *to educate*.

The verb *biliden/bilidōn* ('to form, to replicate') and the noun *bilidi* ('form, image') are both older than the first written records of the German language, so no common ancestor is attested, but their form and meaning are arguably close enough to suppose they have the same root.

If the reconstructed PIE root *biliþī* is accurate, it would definitely be close enough to *biliden/bilidōn* and *bilidi* as well.

All these forms only meant something along the lines of '(to) form, (to) image, (to) model'.

#### The most important change

…happended not before the middle of the 18th century when the term *bilden* ('to form') was applied to the classical humanistic education ideal of 'forming' young people. As *bilden* became popular as a metaphor for *to educate*, the noun *Bildung* got its present-day meaning and popularity.

This late shift of meaning explains why they mean seem unrelated at first. But until about 1750, *Bildung* meant 'image making, forming', thus the relation to *Bild* ('image, form').

And today, *Bildung* can still mean 'creation, formation'. Contemporary examples:

> ein Team **bilden**
> *to form a team*

> Team**bildung**
> *team formation*

> eine Schlange **bilden**
> *to queue/line up* (literally: *to form a snake*)

> bildende Kunst
> *visual (~imaging)/plastic arts* (**not:** educating arts)

> Staats**bildung**
> *nation building*

Comment: It is also still used in a more literal sense: _Schlackebildung_, _Rußbildung_.

Comment: The Dutch understanding of *beeld* is 'sculpture', also playing into the 'sculpturing' towards 'sculpture´ concept.

Answer (score 2):

The **"-ung"** in **Bild-ung** does not relate to the **Bild** part, because a **Bild** is not a process.
There is no reason for a **Bild** to ever need an **-ung** at the end.
This **-ung** relates to the process the **Bild** is a product of, which is some not further defined variant of **-Machung** or **-Formung** or **-Gebung**.
In this case the resulting **Bild** is that of character or ability or imago even, rather than a visual image or a statue.
So **Bildung** not only relates to, but actually is a process involving a **Bild**.